# Google code Wiki Homepage

Tags: wiki, google-code

How can I be able to set a wiki page as a homepage (make it appear every time I click on the "Wiki" tab)  in my google code project.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your GoogleCode site, click "Administer", then "Tabs". In the form that appears, you can customize which wiki pages are to be used for the "Downloads"/"Wiki"/"Issues"/"Source" tabs.